# is iptables broken or is it a kernel related issue?

Tags: pi-3, iptables, kali

I am trying to setup an access point on a raspberry pi 3 v1.2 using this repository create_ap with this Wifi adapter

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

I tried creating an AP with this adapter in a Kali vm on my pc and it works flawlessly but on the raspberry pi it returns a weird error

```
iptables v1.8.4 (nf_tables): Couldn't load match `tcp':No such file or directory
```

so I think this is a software software problem

when trying the following commands on the raspberry

```
iptables -t nat -L
iptables -S 
iptables -L
```

I get the following error for all three commands

```
iptables v1.8.4 (nf_tables): Could not fetch rule set generation id: Invalid argument
```

I tried reinstalling hostapd and dnsmasq also the iptables but i was not successful at all

the kernel on the kali vm is

```
Linux 5.5.0-kali2-amd64
```

and the kernel on the raspberry is

```
Linux 4.19.93-Re4son-v8+
```

both the vm and raspberry are running Kali Linux downloaded from the official site

both WiFi adapters on the raspberry support AP mode and i checked that using this command

```
iw list
```

I  am not asking for a couple of commands to write or a script to run and fix my problem i asking for explanation for this problem and guidelines where to look and if i have missed something

Comment: the problem is that the nf_tables module doesn't exist for `4.19.93-Re4son-v8+` - though it does for `4.19.93-Re4son-v8l+` - do you know the difference between `v8+` and `v8l+` - because I haven't been able to figure it out :p

Comment: of the four 4.19.93 kernels (v7+, v7l+, v8+ and v8l+) - three have about 1600 kernel modules, and the v8+ has only 1300 kernel modules - not sure why

Comment: you could try `iptables-legacy` in place of `iptables`

Comment: Ran into the same issue while trying set up iptables for a pi-hole. I ran iptables-legacy to see if it spit out any information. That command spit out `Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied` Seems the issue is a permissions issue, and the error is just not helpful on the newer version of iptables on Raspbian. Adding `sudo` to the start of my command worked for me. Alternatively, you can run `su` and login, but keep in mind this will give you enough permissions to properly screw up your installation if you type a bad command.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this to work with a workaround by replacing iptables with iptables-legacy (mainly to get ufw working)

You will need to do the following:

```
sudo touch /run/xtables.lock
sudo chmod a+r /run/xtables.lock
```

Easier to perform the next steps as root

```
sudo su - root
```

The following will move the iptables app that not working and copy the working legacy app

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /usr/sbin/iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-broken
cp /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy /usr/sbin/iptables
mv /usr/sbin/iptables-restore /usr/sbin/iptables-restore-broken
mv /usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore /usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore-broken
mv /usr/sbin/iptables-save /usr/sbin/iptables-save-broken
mv /usr/sbin/ip6tables-save /usr/sbin/ip6tables-save-broken
cp /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy-restore /usr/sbin/iptables-restore
cp /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy-restore /usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore
cp /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy-save /usr/sbin/iptables-save
cp /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy-save /usr/sbin/ip6tables-save
```

Comment: This worked for me on installing `docker.io` on `Kali Linux 2020.3 4.19.118-Re4son-v8+ aarch64`

Comment: wow........ it FIXED for me... I was getting mad because I couldn't install docker-ce. It countinued to fail the installation......... THANKS!!!!